# Lazy load for nonnavigation property in EF 4.1

Tags: mapping, entity-framework-4.1, lazy-loading

Is there a simple solution to make lazy load for nonnavigation property in the EF 4.1? For example, for byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No EF doesn't provide lazy loading for scalar and complex properties. The trick is to use table splitting where data from single table are mapped into two entities related with one-to-one relation. One entity is the principal and it contains navigation property to the dependent and because of that you can use lazy loading. [Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390172/how-to-map-table-splitting-in-ef-code-first) with link how to do it in EDMX and the answer provides solution for mapping in code-first (comments contains link to another example in MSDN forum).

Comment: @zonder, +1, totally agree with you. That "Table-splitting" strategy is the ugliest workaround for absense of such a necessary feature as regular ordinary lazy-loading.

Comment: EF s*cks. I have a table with an xml payload that I would like to be able to exclude some (actually most) of the time. Do you think I can - no. I have decided to just load it for now, and I am going back to creating connections manually. I always end up tossing these frameworks after a short while. Time and time again.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of any situation where you'd desire a lazy loaded column in a table and couldn't justify putting it in its own table and mapping a separate entity to represent it.  If you want a column lazy loaded, its probably a good indication that you need to create a separate entity.  If you are mapping EF to a legacy database, then ignore everything I just said.

Comment: For example, when you need to use entity for displaying in a list and for creating or updating. You don't need to load all the infroration of entity in case of a list. That's one of a lot situation when you need to use just part of entity data.

Comment: Anything bigger than a simple string, like image data, xml or other such payload data that is attached to an entity. Why should I have to create a one-to-one relationship and indexes every time I have an image / xml or whatever. One to one relationships are a pain at the best of times, so why proliferate them.