# Loading POCO partially

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a Table with these columns

```
Id as integer
Name as string
Image as byte()
```

then I made two POCO

```
Public Class TableBase
     Id as Integer
     Name as String
End Class

Public Class Table
    Inherts TableBase
    Image as byte()
End Class.
```

Because I not always I need to load the image.
The problem is that I received a discrimination error, and the solutions of TPH stuff don’t resolve it. Because I can’t add a discrimination column to database table.

```
   ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Table>()
    .Map(mc => mc.Requires("TableType").HasValue("Base"))
   ...
```

Actually I don’t have a hierarchy problem; I just need to load POCO partially

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need TPH because in TPH record in the database can be represented by only one entity type - that means it will be either `TableBase` or `Table` but never both.

You need [table splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390172/how-to-map-table-splitting-in-ef-code-first).

Comment: Actually after a lot of reading I think your are right, the best solution is table splitting. thats mean an inconvenience for me because my  Razor Views are created with Reflection in runtime.

By the way, I will leave to inherit in my POCO :(