# EF 4.1, POCO: Lazy-loading for complex type (2 types mapping the same table)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, lazy-loading, poco

Is it possible to set up Address (complex type) being lazy loaded for Customer in this example: [Entity Framework 4.1 – Component mapping](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-%E2%80%93-component-mapping/) ?

I needed it to optimize my SQL queries, so that sometimes I do not need complex type being loaded, sometimes I do. I do not want to deal with LINQ's Select() with DTOs.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. EF doesn't support lazy loading of complex types ([properties of complex type cannot be null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx)). You must either refactor your application and use address as separate table or use [table splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390172/how-to-map-table-splitting-in-ef-code-first). In both cases your address becomes separate entity with navigation properties and you will be able to control its loading.