# creating strict 1 to 1 relationship by code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I want to create a 1 to 1 relationship by code first, below is my code,

```
class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonDetail detail { get; set; }
}

class PersonDetail
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public virtual Person person { get; set; }
}

class EFTest : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> personSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonDetail> detailSet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasRequired(x => x.detail).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.person);
    }
}
```

But I still can insert a person without person detail. I'm trying to create a 1 to 1 relationship in model first, it works well, if I insert one end without the other end, there will be an exception thrown. Why code first with the code above create a 1 to 0..1 relationship?

Anyone can help?

Comment: Is there a reason you want Person and PersonDetail seperate, instead of just putting them in the same entity?  If one cannot live without the other, it doesn't seem like there's an advantage to model them seperate.  I have done what you want before(not in EF, but using constraints in the DB) and it really just creates a headache.  Anytime I try to insert either record, there is an error because it's partner does not exist.  There is no way to insert two records simultaneously.  Thus you would have to drop the constraints, insert both records, and then enable the constraints again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible only if both `Person` and `PersonDetail` will be mapped to the same table (the mapping technique is called Table Splitting) because strict 1:1 means that you cannot insert `Person` without existing `PersonDetail` but you also cannot insert `PersonDetail` without existing `Person` => you cannot insert either of them because the dependency will be always missing (remember each record has its own insert command and database check the integrity after each command not after transaction).

Only when you use [table splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390172/how-to-map-table-splitting-in-ef-code-first) EF will create single insert command containing data from both entities. In your entity model it will look like two entities with 1:1 mapping but in database it will be single table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please tell me how the model first achieve that goal?

Comment: Hi, @Ladislav Mrnka, any ideas?

Comment: Model first will not create table splitting for you. It would require changing the generation process to identify one-to-one relation and create single table for related entities. That would be quite complex change.